# Is drawing with a pen on my wrist regularly unhealthy?

Tags: dermatology

Does the "black" ink of a ballpoint pen affect my health in any way, especially if it's applied in the same general area over a larger period of time?

Answer (score 2):

- It is usually only a problem in [Ink poisoning](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002791.htm):

> Writing ink poisoning occurs when someone swallows ink found in
> writing instruments (pens).

And

- [Allergies to skin:](http://www.livestrong.com/article/22877-ink-poisoning-symptoms/) Irritation to skin, burning or itching. Which are rare the main adverse effect is usually only staining do the dye in the ink.
- [Cuts in the skin and permanent ink can cause problems.](http://www.wisegeek.org/is-it-true-that-writing-on-skin-is-unhealthy-or-risky.htm)

> The primary concern with writing on skin with permanent ink is that
> permanent ink may contain xylene. Xylene is a toxic substance, though
> toxicity is normally linked to inhalation.
>
> People can cause damage to their skin however, by cutting the skin and
> then writing on skin with a permanent marker.

- I can find no evidence of a greater problem over time, unless you were referring to developing a allergy which is possible, but I found no evidence to support that statement.

### Additional Info

- [FDA.gov](http://www.fda.gov/forconsumers/consumerupdates/ucm048919.htm) - About Tattoo ink
- Skeptics SE - [Can you get ink poisoning from drawing or writing on your skin with pen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18586/can-you-get-ink-poisoning-from-drawing-or-writing-on-your-skin-with-pen)